# sbt eclipse でエラー

Tags: java, eclipse, sbt

JavaでPlay Frameworkを使おうと思い

[Javaフレームワーク「Play Framework」でWeb APIを作成する（1）](https://devlog.mescius.jp/java-play-framework-web-api-1/#sbt)

を参考にEclipseに対応させようと
`sbt eclipse`
コマンドを実行すると以下のエラーが出ました。

ググったところdependencyOverridesと言うのを設定すればいいらしいのですが、どのファイルにどうやって書けばよいかわかりません。

どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

```
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[error]
[error]         * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:2.2.0 (early-semver) is selected over {2.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.1.1}
[error]             +- org.playframework.twirl:twirl-api_2.12:2.0.1       (depends on 2.2.0)
[error]             +- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.18              (depends on 2.1.0)
[error]             +- org.foundweekends.giter8:giter8-lib_2.12:0.16.2    (depends on 2.1.0)
[error]             +- com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.3.20 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12) (depends on 1.1.1)
[error]             +- com.typesafe.play:twirl-api_2.12:1.4.2             (depends on 1.2.0)
[error]             +- com.github.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.9.16 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (depends on 2.1.0)
[error]
[error]
[error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel
[error]         at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:90)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:134)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:74)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:147)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:147)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:128)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:220)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:161)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$1(Defaults.scala:3801)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:63)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:69)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:283)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:24)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:292)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:283)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:65)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
[error] (update) found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[error]
[error]         * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:2.2.0 (early-semver) is selected over {2.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.1.1}
[error]             +- org.playframework.twirl:twirl-api_2.12:2.0.1       (depends on 2.2.0)
[error]             +- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.18              (depends on 2.1.0)
[error]             +- org.foundweekends.giter8:giter8-lib_2.12:0.16.2    (depends on 2.1.0)
[error]             +- com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.3.20 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12) (depends on 1.1.1)
[error]             +- com.typesafe.play:twirl-api_2.12:1.4.2             (depends on 1.2.0)
[error]             +- com.github.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.9.16 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (depends on 2.1.0)
[error]
[error]
[error] this can be overridden using libraryDependencySchemes or evictionErrorLevel
```